# Time-dependent action.. is late?

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I have a workflow with a time-dependent action. The trigger is correctly scheduled (if I go to "monitoring" I see the fire date being set at the appropriate time). But then action actually fires a couple of minutes later.

Is this an expected behavior of Sfdc? If so, is there an apex way to execute something in an exact point in time, i.e. I know the datetime at which this event will occur but it's not periodical therefore I can't use batch scheduled actions.

Thank you very much for your attention!
T.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe there is any guarantee about when a timed workflow will trigger - as stated in the docs : "Time-dependent actions aren't executed independently. They're processed several times every hour, where they're grouped together and executed as a single batch."

I don't know of any way to guarantee a time - all async operations operate based on "available resources" to my knowledge...

Comment: While we (meaning external developers) do not know the internal mechanics, previous testing shows that when the server starts up, a cron-tab type process runs every 15 minutes, and all items that are past due or will be due in the next 7 minutes or so will be processed.